# Swift 4 http get e iterar a resposta JSON

Tags: json, swift, get, swift-playground

Olá,
Estou aprendendo Swift e estou fazendo uma requisição GET via URL que me retorna um JSON com essa estrutura.

```
{
 "data": {
 "response": [
 "https://s3.amazonaws.com/meusite/minhapasta/banners/banner-01.png",
 "https://s3.amazonaws.com/meusite/minhapasta/banners/banner-02.png",
 "https://s3.amazonaws.com/meusite/minhapasta/banners/banner-03.png"
 ]
 }
 }
```

.

No Playground estou fazendo assim para requisitar o JSON

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

// Seta a URL
let url = URL(string: "https://adm.meusite.com.br/api/app/v1/1/usuarios/banners")!
    // faz a requisição retornando data, response, error
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    //checa se tem erro
    guard error == nil else {
        // Exibe o erro
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
        // encerra e não executa o restante do código
        return
    }
    // Remove do optional
    if  let data = data,
        // pega o conteudo do JSON converte para string
        let contents = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        // Printa o JSON como String
        print(contents)

    }

 }
// Encerra a requisição
task.resume()
```

Eu gostaria de saber como iterar esse JSON, substituindo esse trecho pela iteração de dicionary:

```
// pega o conteudo do JSON converte para string
let contents = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        // Printa o JSON como String
        print(contents)

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voce pode usar um metodo de `JSONSerialization` chamado `jsonObject(with: Data)` que convert os dados retornados pela API num object do tipo Any. Depois você precisa fazer o cast do tipo `Any` pra dicionário `[String:Any]` e acessar os elementos fazendo também os casts subsequentes de `Any` pro tipo correspondente:

```
do {
    if let jsonObject = (try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)) as? [String: Any],
        let dictionary = jsonObject["data"] as? [String: Any],
        let response = (dictionary["response"] as? [String])?.flatMap({URL(string: $0)}) {
        print(response)  // "[https://s3.amazonaws.com/meusite/minhapasta/banners/banner-01.png, https://s3.amazonaws.com/meusite/minhapasta/banners/banner-02.png, https://s3.amazonaws.com/meusite/minhapasta/banners/banner-03.png]\n"
        for url in response {
            print(url)
        }
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Outra opção que você tem se estiver usando **Xcode 9.x • Swift 4** é criar uma estrutura `Codable`:

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let data: Response
    struct Response: Codable {
        let response: [URL]
    }
}
```

E depois é só usar o `JSONDecoder` pra decodificar os dados retornados pela sua API:

```
do {
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data).data.response
    print(response)  // "[https://s3.amazonaws.com/meusite/minhapasta/banners/banner-01.png, https://s3.amazonaws.com/meusite/minhapasta/banners/banner-02.png, https://s3.amazonaws.com/meusite/minhapasta/banners/banner-03.png]\n"
    for url in response {
        print(url)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Estou usando Xcode 9 com Swift 4 mesmo... E no caso do json ser assim: {"data": [{"id": "1","attributes": {"nome-fantasia": "Empresa 1","telefones": [{"numero": "(00) 0000-0000"}]}},{"id": "2","attributes": {"nome-fantasia": "Empresa 2","telefones": [{"numero": "(00) 0000-0000"}]}}]}. Como ficaria o class (ou o struct)? O data sendo um Array de Dictionaries. E onde leio sobre isso? tem alguma dica?

Comment: @CarlosFagianiJr Essa estrutura ficaria um pouco mais complicada, mas uma vez que você tenha entendido como estruturar os seu dados fica bem mais fácil, é só uma questão de prática. Em relação a alguma referência eu vou procurar a documentação e te passo os links. Eu acho que seria melhor voce abrir outra pergunta que eu coloco a resposta la pra você.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types e https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/using_json_with_custom_types

Comment: tenho um caso parecido com esse mas meu json vem de maneira diferente [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "description": "teste3",
        "live": "https://....",
        "thumb": "http......",
        "online": true
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "description": "teste2",
        "live": "https://....",
        "thumb": "http......",
        "online": true
    }] nao consegui implementar com o exemplo de vcs podem me ajudar

Comment: @JoãoVitor seja qual for o formato dos dados o máximo que pode acontecer é você ter de criar um custom decoder initializer.

Comment: pode me mandar um exemplo

Comment: Isso depende também pra que tipo de dados. Date?

Comment: pego a resposta do alamofire  geralmente pego o response.data

Comment: é só determinar no JSONDecoder qual o  dateDecodingStrategy. Se a sua data tiver fractional seconds ai fica mais complicado

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71482/discussion-between-joao-vitor-and-leo-dabus).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46458487/how-to-convert-a-date-string-with-optional-fractional-seconds-using-codable-in-s/46458771?s=4|0.0000#46458771